# navigation menu question with jquery and sharepoint list

Tags: jquery

I want to build a jquery tab menu using data from a sharepoint list.
 So i decided to use SPServices from codeplex to get the data via webservices as i would be using it from different site collections- this is a Sharepoint  foundation site.
my question is should i build my menu first with data first and then use jquery later to structure and style the menu?
Or should i just dump the html e.g div and li and the later use jquery to query the html data.
Why 'm asking this is i would like to pass querystring with a prameter in the url to the SP list so that i can have the menu selected on the fly e.g default.aspx?selected=HOME so the HOME link would be selected with a background color.

How to use jquery to achieve this just need some guides and samples
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using a DVWP for this instead, though you say that you want to use it in multiple Site Collections, so perhaps that is a mitigating factor.

I don't have an example of exactly what you're trying to do with SPServices, but which path you take should probably be more influenced by what you're most comfortable with rather than some stock answer. If *I* were to do it, I'd probably build the list first, then get the data from the list with GetListItems, then do the formatting.

Comment: Marc thanks for the reply and actually i have done it that way
I have used the SPservices for a lot of my jquery integration and i must say its cool.
I think my question is really regarding formatting it to the menu.
I want to use it for a tab menu but when a user selects a tab i want to keep the link highlighted and selected and both parent and child should be selected.
Thanks

Comment: I'd rough out the structure first and then worry about the behavior. In other words, first make it work, then make it look nice.